# How to load the particular colIndex data from Mysql to TextBox in extjs

Tags: extjs

I am trying to load the data from MySQL database to textFiled, instead of clicking on the Grid in Extjs.

I want something like without use of Grid.. because I wanted to load only that particular User to view his private things.

Please Suggest the coding for this.
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has worked, what didn't? Please provide code and try to think for yourself (or use a search engine) first. Are you sure that nobody has tried this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you build a form in a form panel and then load the record and put it into the form:

```
var user = Ext.ModelManager.getModel('UserModel').load(userId);
Ext.getCmp('form').loadRecord(user);
```

the name of the form fields must be set like the fields of the user model.